# How to make the TFS build fail when number of warnings is increased compared to the last build

Tags: vbscript

I am new to TFS. (using TFS 2012 and vs 2008)I may be asking some very basic questions. How to make the TFS build fail when number of warnings is increased compared to the last build? I am willing to write vbscript/perl for it. 
Finally I also want track also is there a new warning type compared to the last build?
If some guidance is provided.
Will it better be integrated as postbuild event?
Do i need to create a new Build Quality(in msft jargon)?

Answer (score 2):

Check below article explaining how to do that. It has link to the Xaml file as well.

http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/03/28/fail-a-build-when-the-warning-count-increases/

You might be able to use something similar for your second question about warning type as well.